# Oracle - Getting the fields of all tables in a database

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I know that to find all the fields of a table I should use something like

```
sqlplus > desc testtable;
```

This lists all the fields of a table (here testtable)

But now, I have a list of tables in my database.

**What is the way through which I can get the fields of all tables
 in a given database using sqlplus?** 
I tried

```
 sqlplus > desc <Databasename>; which didnot work.
```

Someone told me to use

```
sqlplus > select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ; //gives error.

SQLPLUS > SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS; //gives some error.
```

(At the bottom line, I am trying to get the database schema.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the information_schema tables you can find in other dbs (SQL Server, PostGres, MySQL, etc) is in Oracle.  I use to use the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table to get at that type of information....maybe another alternative.

Link: [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)

Comment: Thanks scarpacci. But still when I use sqlplus> select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS doesnot give me the tables under a database.

Comment: Now it works.. select table_name from user_Tab_columns; (all in caps) lists all the tables. Thanks scarpacci..

Comment: Cool glad you were able to get what you needed

Comment: `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` describes the columns of all tables, views, and clusters in the database.

`USER_TAB_COLUMNS` describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters owned by the current user. This view does not display the OWNER column.